# Fill NAs values with combination of incremental number and column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, increment

I have the following dataframe:

```
        UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER   COUNTRY_CODE
        
0          1                    CZ
1         nan                   CZ
2          2                    SK
3          4                    AE
4        nan                    DK
5        nan                    CZ
6        nan                    DK
7        nan                    ES
```

For all blank values in the "UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER" column, I would like to create a value that takes the "COUNTRY_CODE" and add incremental numbers (with a space in between the number and the Country Code) starting from 1 for each different country code. So the final dataframe would be this:

```
        UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER   COUNTRY_CODE
        
0          1                    CZ
1         CZ 1                  CZ
2          2                    SK
3          4                    AE
4        DK 1                   DK
5        CZ 2                   CZ
6        DK 2                   DK
7        ES 1                   ES
```

What would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) only for missing rows by `UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER` and add `COUNTRY_CODE` values with space separator:

```
m = df.UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER.isna()
s = df[m].groupby('COUNTRY_CODE').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
df.loc[m, 'UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER'] = df.loc[m, 'COUNTRY_CODE'] + ' ' + s
print (df)
  UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER COUNTRY_CODE
0               1.0           CZ
1              CZ 1           CZ
2               2.0           SK
3               4.0           AE
4              DK 1           DK
5              CZ 2           CZ
6              DK 2           DK
7              ES 1           ES
```

Or use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for replace missing values:

```
s = df[df.UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER.isna()].groupby('COUNTRY_CODE').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
df['UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER'] = df['UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER'].fillna(df['COUNTRY_CODE'] + ' ' + s)
print (df)
  UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER COUNTRY_CODE
0               1.0           CZ
1              CZ 1           CZ
2               2.0           SK
3               4.0           AE
4              DK 1           DK
5              CZ 2           CZ
6              DK 2           DK
7              ES 1           ES
```

**Details**:

```
print (df[m].groupby('COUNTRY_CODE').cumcount().add(1).astype(str))
1    1
4    1
5    2
6    2
7    1
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an incremental count with [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), then add 1 and convert to string, and use it either to [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) (option #1) or to replace the values with [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) (option #2):

```
s = df['COUNTRY_CODE'].where(df['UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER'].isna(), '')

df['UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER'] = (df['UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER']
                          .fillna(s+' '+s.groupby(s).cumcount()
                                         .add(1).astype(str))
                          )
```

or:

```
m = df['UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER'].isna()
s = df['COUNTRY_CODE'].where(m, '')
df.loc[m, 'UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER'] = s+' '+s.groupby(s).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
```

output:

```
  UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER COUNTRY_CODE
0               1.0           CZ
1              CZ 1           CZ
2               2.0           SK
3               4.0           AE
4              DK 1           DK
5              CZ 2           CZ
6              DK 2           DK
7              ES 1           ES
```